# Laravel Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel 5.7.13 blog which works very well on my local server. But after deploying it to live shared cpanel server, the database won't connect even after i have updated my .evn file.

**.env updated file:**

```
APP_NAME=EXTRAKOBO
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:1Z6bkcUcgfoN6+cWghKDhRglrQStTg7aXaZI=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ondi_myblog
DB_USERNAME=ondi_blog
DB_PASSWORD=abcd13
```

**Below is the error that I am getting:**

```
/home/ondi/miniblog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php

/**
 * @param  array     $bindings
 * @param  \Closure  $callback
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Database\QueryException
 */
protected function runQueryCallback($query, $bindings, Closure $callback)
{
    // To execute the statement, we'll simply call the callback, which will actually
    // run the SQL against the PDO connection. Then we can calculate the time it
    // took to execute and log the query SQL, bindings and time in our memory.
    try {
        $result = $callback($query, $bindings);
    }

    // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new QueryException(
            $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
        );
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Arguments

```
1. "SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'ondi_blog'@'localhost' 
   (using password: YES) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `posts`)"
```

Please I will need help to resolve this issue. Thank you for your assistance

Comment: you tried to run php artisan config:clear after you set new password in the .env file?

Comment: @shushu304; Please how do I do that as I am already on a live cpanel server?

Comment: you don't have access to shell in this server? you can try to ask the support to this for you ... but i assume that it will not be use full for the long run ... try to do it in a workaround and calling artisan programmatically, look at this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands

Comment: you should change `APP_URL` when you are uploading a project on live server.

Comment: What actually should I change it to? @Dhruv Raval; Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on DB_HOST. All these while, my DB_HOST had been 127.0.0.1. Even when I changed it to "localhost", it still didn't work.
But as soon as i changed it to the host server name, it worked for me at ones. The host server name can be gotten from phpMyAdmin under database in the cpanel where you import your database to. Above Database box at the top left side, your host database name is there. Just copy and paste on the DB_HOST.

Mine is mysql20001.mochahost.com (Though I removed the .mochahost.com) and that's it, it worked for me. The new code now looks like this on the .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql20001
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ondi_myblog
DB_USERNAME=ondi_blog
DB_PASSWORD=abcd13
```

Comment: Mission Passed! Thank you for this, I searching for long time until find your answer and it helps me to fix the problem, for me DB_HOST is `mysql2001.my-virtual-panel.com` and works.

Answer (score 3):

As you are already on server, so you can't do artisan command.
You can do something like that.

```
Route::get('/clear-config', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:clear');
    return "config clear";

});
```

Comment: Please where do I add the code listed above? I am actually new to laravel. Thank you

Comment: You have to add this code in your routes folder web.php file.

Comment: I have just done that @Md.Sukel Ali; it didnt work still.

Comment: Did you hit the Url  "your-domain-name/clear-config" ?

Answer (score 0):

hi the problem is in your .env  romove the password i think that your phpmyadmin dont have password and root username

Comment: Done that and it gave me the following error >>>    SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'ondi_blog'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `posts`)

Comment: ok know change your username to root and crreate database with name ondi_myblog

Comment: Just did that, nothing still

Comment: give me teamview id and password

Comment: does your wampserver is running

Comment: No it is not running. Actually I'm using xampp

Comment: aahh this is the problem run your phpmyadmin and your apache